How to fetch package with latest version in upstream source in Azure DevOps Artifact feed?
I have a npm project that build with Azure DevOps Artifact feed.
Consider the following case:
Our project has a dependency on @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.3. This package has a dependency "axios": "^1.6.5". Now, I want to update @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.3 to v2.13.4. @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.4 also has the dependency "axios": "^1.6.5". The latest version of axios in the public registry is 1.7.4, however, in our private feed, the latest version of axios is 1.6.8.
when I install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.4 with private feed connected, axios v1.6.8 is used.
So, the question is How can I install it with the latest version from the upstream source instead? and what is the best practice?

I download the public package version @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.4, and from the package.json of this package version, I can see below sets of "dependencies".
{
  . . .

  "version": "2.13.4",
  "name": "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli",

  . . .

  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/axios": "3.0.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "10.3.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "10.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/opencollective": "0.3.2",
    "axios": "1.6.8",
    "chalk": "4.1.2",
    "commander": "8.3.0",
    "compare-versions": "4.1.4",
    "concurrently": "6.5.1",
    "console.table": "0.10.0",
    "fs-extra": "10.1.0",
    "glob": "7.2.3",
    "https-proxy-agent": "7.0.4",
    "inquirer": "8.2.6",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "tslib": "2.6.2"
  }
}

I noticed that it is "axios": "1.6.8" instead of "axios": "^1.6.8". The set of "axios": "1.6.8" will only match the package version axios v1.6.8 as the available dependency for @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.4.


Thanks for pointing this out! I finally got it. When @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli v2.13.4 was published, axios v1.7.4 was not published yet. I am not experienced in NPM. Does it mean that a published package has the dependency version fixed? and we do not need to worry about the fetching the latest version from the upstream source?

@Kit, Yes, I think so. And since the package axios has been published, users could not update the configurations of it to use a new version of the dependences when downloading/installing it. If the package axios is changed to use a new version of the dependences, it normally would be released a new version of it.
